# Matrix with dynamic dimension in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, while-loop

In a do-while loop until its end, in each iteration a new column should be added to a predefined matrix. I couldn't find how to define such a matrix in matlab? is there a standard method for defining such matrix with dynamic dimension?

Note: The do-while loop is simulated by a for loop

```
A=zeros(100,?);
for i=1:inf
A(:,i)=some computation ;

*condition*
end
```

Comment: Matlab does not require initialisation of objects, so what is the problem? just add the column.  Maybe I would understand better if you had the code posted up there

Comment: There is no standard method and it is usually not recommended for performance. If there is a way to know how many columns (and rows obviously) the matrix will eventually have before you enter the loop then you should declare the matrix at the right size at the start. If you really have to change the size dynamically, there are ways to limit the performance hit but we'd need to see your code to propose anything ...

Comment: infinite `for` loop is not possible. even if it is made possible (by replacing `for` with `while`) then you can never have infinite memory for `A`

Comment: @SardarUsama, It iterates until the condition is true.

Comment: @PhoenixBlue, The question has been updated.

Comment: Choose a sufficiently large number for pre-allocation that can accommodate whatever biggest rough estimation of that matrix that you can have. Then remove the extra entries at the end. If there is absolutely no way possible to make such an estimation then use a cell array; it is much much less harmful in the perspective of performance when you intend to append

Answer (score 3):

Although the code here below works, you may consider @Sardar_Usama suggestion, working with cells. But I'm not too good with those...

```
A = zeros(100, 20); % initial number of columns is 20, but can grow larger
col = 1;
while(condition)
    A(:, col) = result of some computation;
    col = col + 1;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

matlab dynamically handles matrix sizes. So you can use add new columns or rows easily. However, it can degrade the performance of the algorithm. some examples:

```
A= ones(10,4);
B = zeros(10,2);
C = rand(3,4);
A = [A B]; % adds two new columns consisting of B to the end of A
A = [C; A];% adds three new rows consisting of C to the beginning of A
```